# Insert Python Dictionary into Neo4j

Tags: python, neo4j

I am trying to insert a Python dictionary into a bare Neo4j Database. These tweets are gathered on a change stream from a MongoDB Collection. I am brand new to Neo4j and want to use it to visualize the relationships between tweets, users, hashtags, and user mentions.

I know I with MongoDB you can bulk upload basically a list of dictionaries into  a collection but can you do the same with Neo4j?

Do I have to create the Nodes prior to inserting the records or can I do it all in code?

```
def insert_neo4j(tweets):

for tweet in tweets:
    id = tweet.get("_id")
    user = tweet.get("Author")
    text = tweet.get("Text")
    hashtags = tweet.get("Hashtags")
    user_mentions = tweet.get("User Mentions")
```

Comment: you need to define a graph model before you can import the data.

Comment: Can I do that in python or can I do it beforehand in the Neo4J GUI?

Comment: Either way is fine, you will need to come up with a cypher query

Answer (score 0):

Export your dictionary to csv file(s), perhaps via pandas, and then load into Neo4j. For the later there are at least 3 options

LOAD CSV ... small file

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000 LOAD CSV  ... iterative

CALL apoc.periodic.iterate ... best for large files; minimizes deadlocks